# Is this multiply-divide function correct?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math, numbers

I'm trying to avoid `long long`s and integer overflow in some calculations, so I came up with the function below to calculate `(a * b) / c` (order is important due to truncating integer division).

```
 unsigned muldiv(unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned c)
 {
      return a * (b / c) + (a * (b % c)) / c;
 }
```

Are there any edge cases for which this won't work as expected?

Comment: You don't say *why* you're avoiding `long long` but if it's for speed I strongly suspect any extra div/mod operation will dwarf the savings.

Comment: I assume you've checked for `c=0`.

Comment: You did not mention if you want the output to be an integer or a double - since you are doing division. If it is the overflow issue you are worried about, then you may normalize 'a', 'b', and 'c' and then (un)normalize the result. By normalization, I mean divide/multiply by a power of 10.

Comment: @Ben Jackson: I'm not avoiding long long for speed, it's an arbitrary constraint. @twain249: Yes, yes I have. @Santosh Tiwari: The function signature has a return type of `unsigned`, so integer output it is.

Comment: Also, I do expect the usual unsigned wrapping if `(a * b) / c` can't fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDITED: This is correct for a superset of values for which the original obvious logic was correct. It still buys you nothing if `c` > `b` and possibly in other conditions. Perhaps you know something about your values of `c` but this may not help as much as you expect. Some combinations of `a`, `b`, `c` will still overflow.

EDIT: Assuming you're avoiding `long long` for strict C++98 portability reasons, you can get about 52 bits of precision by promoting your `unsigned` to `double`s that happen to have integral values to do the math. Using `double` math may in fact be faster than doing three integral divisions.

Comment: if `c > b` this turns into `(a * b) / c` because the first term drops out and `b % c` = `b`. Also since that will be < `a` it can't overflow (because `a` fits).

Comment: Perhaps, but I'm not sure that I can reliably calculate every possible `(a * b) / c`with `double`.

Comment: @Electro You can't, but depending on the distribution of your `b`, `b`, `c` it could be many more than your original approach. If you really need to be able to handle every possible input value I strongly suggest just biting the bullet and using `long long`.

Comment: It's also entirely possible I might have to multiply-divide with `unsigned long long`s, and that's about as long as you get without using something like GMP. I just want to know whether this procedure holds in C++98 for any unsigned integers `a`, `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 4):

This fails on quite a few cases.  The most obvious is when `a` is large, so `a * (b % c)` overflows.  You might try swapping `a` and `b` in that case, but that still fails if `a`, `b`, and `c` are all large.  Consider `a` = `b` = 2^25-1 and c = 2^24 with a 32 bit unsigned.  The correct result is 2^26-4, but both `a * (b % c)` and `b * (a % c)` will overflow.  Even `(a % c) * (b % c)` would overflow.

By far the easisest way to solve this in general is to have a widening multiply, so you can get the intermediate product in higher precision.  If you don't have that, you need to synthesize it out of smaller multiplies and divides, which is pretty much the same thing as implementing your own biginteger library.

If you can guarentee that `c` is small enough that `(c-1)*(c-1)` will not overflow an unsigned, you could use:

```
unsigned muldiv(unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned c) {
    return (a/c)*(b/c)*c + (a%c)*(b/c) + (a/c)*(b%c) + (a%c)*(b%c)/c;
}
```

This will actually give you the "correct" answer for ALL a and b -- (a * b)/c % (UINT_MAX+1)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid overflow you have to pre-divide and then post-multiply by some factor.

The best factor to use is c, as long as one (or both) of a and b is greater than c.  This is what Chris Dodd's function does.  It has a greatest intermediate of ((a % c) * (b % c)), which, as Chris identifies, is less than or equal to ((c-1)*(c-1)).

If you could have a situation where both a and b are less than c, but (a * b) could still overflow, (which might be the case when c approaches the limit of the word size) then the best factor to use is a large power of two, to turn the multiply and divides into shifts.  Try shifting by half the word size.

Note that using pre-divide and then post-multiplying is the equivalent of using longer words when you don't have longer words available.  Assuming you don't discard the low order bits but just add them as another term, then you are just using several words instead of one larger one.

I'll let you fill the code in.